# Methods for Constructing a Yield Curve

Tags: yield-curve, interpolation

I wonder if the Raw interpolation (known as linear on the log of discount factors) can handle negative interest rate due to the inverted yield curve?

I understand using the linear on log of rates and linear on discount factors does not allow negative interest rate, but what about **linear on the log of discount factors**? For linear methods, I can only use linear on rate to deal with negative interest rate cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Discount factors are never negative so you can take their logarithms. It is then quite trivial to perform a log-linear interpolation on discount factors. Whether rates are positive or negative is irrelevant.